# How to use angular.filter in controller's function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

On change select choosen type and value passed to the function (ng-change="sortEvents(type, value)")

I need to filter all elements of $scope.events to select elements with "state" equal to "NSW" only.

`$scope.sortEvents = function(type, value, $scope, $filter) {
            $scope.events = $filter('filterBy')($scope.events, ['state'], 'NSW');
            console.log($scope.events);
        }`

But in console is see http://prntscr.com/bmyj74
Angular filter works appropriately using ng-repeat, and in app.js in dependencies, I have specified angular.filter.

Comment: you don't need `$scope, $filter` in parameter of function

Comment: Right, but it does not helps

Answer (score 0):

You can write your filter like this:

```
$scope.events = $filter('filter')($scope.events, function(e){
    return e.state === 'NSW';
});
```